# How to convert PDF to image file by flutter

Tags: flutter

I am trying to print image to mobile Bluetooth thermal printer by ESC_POS_UTIL flutter Library, the Library support only image print or Text, so my plane is to render PDF and save to a PDF file by using pdf: ^3.3.0 Library which take job done perfectly, now there is only thing that how can i convert pdf to an image file and save to phone storage in order to print with ESC_POS_UTIL by FLUTTER

1. The code save pdf to file which is perfectly work

[image]

Answer (score 2):

`native_pdf_renderer` is a flutter package that helps to render images from pdf files. Refer https://pub.dev/packages/native_pdf_renderer for more details.
Example code from package documentation:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:native_pdf_renderer/native_pdf_renderer.dart';

void main() async {
  try {
    final document = await PdfDocument.openAsset('assets/sample.pdf');
    final page = await document.getPage(1);
    final pageImage = await page.render(width: page.width, height: page.height);
    await page.close();
    runApp(MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Image(
            image: MemoryImage(pageImage.bytes),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      color: Colors.white,
    ));
  } on PlatformException catch (error) {
    print(error);
  }
}
```

Comment: How can i save to a file like path/pdfToimage.png ?